# Why Missing [ at end-of-block?

Tags: rebol

I copied the source of http://www.ross-gill.com/r/link-up.html to linkup.r and after

do %linkup.r

I got

```
Syntax Error: Missing [ at end-of-block
** Near: (line 89) ]
```

I can't see why it doesn't work ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was a typo in the HTML version - an errant close bracket somehow crept into the page.  Should be fine now, or copy direct from source:

```
write %link-up.r read http://www.ross-gill.com/r/link-up.r
```

Or do direct from the site:

```
do http://www.ross-gill.com/r/link-up.r
```

Comment: Thanks it works now. Does it support multiple lines cause I tried and doesn't seem so.

Comment: Not currently - multiple lines is tricky.  I'd say it can be done, but would take a different approach.  It'd take a lot more code.